# Jquery remove element in array on object prop

Tags: jquery

```
forms.push({
  'form_id'           : form_id,
  'field_name_id'     : $(this).find('input[name=field_name_id]').val(),
  'field_input_type'  : $(this).find('input[name=field_input_type]').val(),
  'field_caption'     : $(this).find('input[name=field_caption]').val()
});
```

My array like this, i want to delete form_id = 3 in array.

```
$.grep(forms, function(el, idx) {return el.form_id == form_id}, true);
```

this method does not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for (i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) { 
    if(forms[i].form_id == 3){
           delete forms[i];
    }
 }
```

You are doing a loop based on the count of `forms` array total element as `forms.length` ..then `forms[i].form_id` is a method to call `object`..based on the condition delete forms array's `index(i)` array by `delete forms[i]`

**Important thing**

Then we can simply use `foreach` for `javascript arrays`.its a simplest than `for` loop..but as per the research `for loop` is faster than `foreach`..this is one of the good explanation for that https://thejsguy.com/2016/07/30/javascript-for-loop-vs-array-foreach.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which may help you:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var forms = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
      address: 'Highway 71'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Peter',
      address: 'Lowstreet 4'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Amy',
      address: 'Apple st 652'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Hannah',
      address: 'Mountain 21'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Michael',
      address: 'Valley 345'
    },
  ];
  var newForms = $.grep(forms, function(obj, index) {
    return obj.id != 3;
  });
  console.log(newForms);
</script>
```

OR you can use `filter` to filter an Object:

```
var object=object.filter(item=> return item.form_id!=3);
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var filteredForm = forms.filter((obj)=> obj.form_id !== 3);
> console.log('Forms:: ', forms);
> ```